# Drupal (7.x) Change content title color in the default Bartik theme

Tags: drupal, colors, themes

By using "Appearance > Settings > Bartik" I can change almost any color and use a custom Color Scheme. So I changed the colors, a black background and bright (blue/white) text. However, the one thing that I can't change in Bartik are those gray content titles. And with my current black background the titles from articles/basic pages and any other content are hardly readable.

I looked in the bartik theme .css files but couldn't find it. I'm sure others must have had this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

open the style.css file in the theme folder and change the following:

```
.node-teaser h2 a {
  color: #181818;
}
```